# How to transform an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array `coords` which is made by mapping two other array `results` and `values`. How can I add a string so that I can refer them in my d3 like `coords.results` for `x` and `coords.values` for my `y`. Here is the code:

```
coords = values.map((x, i) => {
    return [results[i], x];
});

console.log(coords);
```

And this is how my array looks like right now

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done as follows.

```
values.map(v => ({ x: v[0], y: v[1] }));
```

> This produces an array of objects having a property `x` and `y` each.